# Does Redis Clean expired keys on save or bgsave?

Tags: redis

On [redis.io](http://redis.io/topics/expire) it is said, that expired keys are not deleted immediately but on access or every once in a while randomly some are deleted.

Does redis remove all expired keys on a save or bgsave? Or does it write the old keys to disk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read rdb.c source code and you will see that expired keys will not be save

```
        /* Save the expire time */
        if (expiretime != -1) {
            /* If this key is already expired skip it */
            if (expiretime < now) continue;
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Nothing is better than determining an answer from the source.